# Why is my Blazor WASM Application unable to hit API endpoints after publish?

Tags: iis, caching, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I recently hosted my .net7 Blazor WASM application on IIS.  The application has a client, database, and shared project (as outlined in the Microsoft default project).  My problem is that when visiting the site, only the first call that is made to the API works. After that, no endpoints can be hit, UNLESS the user uses <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh the page without referencing the cache.  Then the API call will find the endpoint, but only that one.  It appears that somehow the caching is going wrong, and after anything is cached, the calls no longer work.  Clearing the cache once again allows a single API call to work before a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> is required to navigate to the API endpoint.

There are no errors in the console in web developer tools.
There are no errors in the network tab in web developer tools, the call simply never shows up in the network tab.
The application runs flawlessly when I am debugging, this issue only presents itself after I hosted the program.
The issue persists across Chrome, Firefox, and Microsoft Edge.

The Client project is what you would expect, .razor pages with minimal amounts of C# code. Business logic is housed in what I refer to as "services" that reside in the Shared project. All API calls are done in this service layer in the Shared project.  The Database project houses my web API controllers.

The APIs are called with the `HttpClient` that is initialized in the Client Program.cs, as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
```

Similarly, the Services I inject into the .razor pages of the Client, located in the Shared project, are initialized here. For example, my User service:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<UtilityService>();
```

Has anyone else run into similar problems with a Blazor WASM project, or know of any sort of a solution?  I am not sure if it is specific to Blazor, but I'm guessing it is indirectly specific to the architecture, and that I have something configured incorrectly, be that the scope of the services or something else.

Comment: You will have to share a lot more code for others to reproduce this issue and investigate.

Comment: 1)Check your `service-worker.js` and `service-worker.published.js` files to ensure they aren't caching your API requests.2)set `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate` headers in iis to avoid caching3)Have you tried different browser for a test4)Could you check console to see is there any error or not5) Instead of creating a new instance of `HttpClient`, consider using `IHttpClientFactory` to create your `HttpClient` instances. This is the recommended approach because it manages the `HttpClient` lifetimes and configurations properly.